# Алгоритм эффективного размещения прямоугольных объектов в прямоугольный контейнер

Tags: алгоритм, генетический-алгоритм

Даны размеры контейнера и размеры прямоугольных объектов, которые нужно в нем разместить. Суммарная площадь этих объектов больше, чем площадь контейнера.
Нужно максимально эффективно разместить данные объекты в контейнере (чем меньше площади контейнера не заполнено, тем эффективнее).

Эта задача NP-полная и для ее решения рекомендуют использовать эвристические методы (например генетические алгоритмы). Какое примерное направление решения данной задачи?

Comment: Обычно это называется "задача двумерного раскроя".

Comment: Есть разные алгоритмы дискретной оптимизации для нахождения близких к оптимальному решений NP-полных задач. Какой конкретно алгоритм сработает лучше для вашей задачи - нужно смотреть на практике, подбирать разные подзадачи и эвристики. На coursera есть очень хороший курс на эту тему: discrete optimization

Comment: Простой пример решения используя local search: генерируете случайное валидное решение. Используем эвристику, и пытаемся улучшить его. Например, вытаскиваем случайный прямоугольник из множества неиспользованных, и ищем куда его впихнуть. Выкидываем лишние, и в дырки снова пытаемся закрыть. Если зашли в тупик и решение не улучшается, генерируем снова случайное размещение и т.д.